# Arduino UNO WIFI Rev 2 - MySQL trouble

Tags: arduino-uno-wifi

I'm using an Arduno UNO WiFi Rev 2 and trying to connect to a database, but it does not connect nor shows any errors.

The arduino connects successfully to WiFi and pinging google works fine.
But when I add the part to connect to database, on line: 65, the script just stops at "DB Connecting..." on the line above.

Inside Arduino IDE you can see a difference between the includes, the MySQL ones are not luminated:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERD0N.png

This is how the code looks like:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>

// MySQL Information
IPAddress server_addr(111,222,333,4);
char user[] = "arduino"; // MySql username
char password[] = "qwerty"; // MySql password

WiFiClient client;
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);

// WiFi Information
char ssid[] = "Router-SSID";        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "router-pw";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;     // the WiFi radio's status

// Specify IP address or hostname
String hostName = "www.google.com";
int pingResult;
int pingWorks = 0;

void setup() {    
  pinMode(hallPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT); 

  Serial.begin(115200);

  // check for the WiFi module:
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
  }

  String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
  if (fv < "1.0.0") {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
  }

  // attempt to connect to WiFi network:
  while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network:
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

    // wait 5 seconds for connection:
    delay(5000);
  }

  // you're connected now, so print out the data:
  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");

  printCurrentNet();
  printWiFiData();

  delay(2000);
  Serial.println(server_addr);
  Serial.println(user);
  Serial.println(password);
  // Connected to the WiFi lets continue..
  Serial.println("DB - Connecting...");
  if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password)) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print ( "." );
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to connect..");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected.");
}

void loop() {
  runWifi();
}

void runWifi() {
  if (pingWorks == 0) {
    Serial.print("Pinging ");
    Serial.print(hostName);
    Serial.print(": ");

    pingResult = WiFi.ping(hostName);

    if (pingResult >= 0) {
      Serial.print("SUCCESS! RTT = ");
      Serial.print(pingResult);
      Serial.println(" ms");
      pingWorks = 1;
    } else {
      Serial.print("FAILED! Error code: ");
      Serial.println(pingResult);
      pingWorks = 2;
    }
  } else {
    Serial.println("Ping on google works..");
  }
  delay(200);
}

void printWiFiData() {
  // print your board's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP address : ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  Serial.print("Subnet mask: ");
  Serial.println((IPAddress)WiFi.subnetMask());

  Serial.print("Gateway IP : ");
  Serial.println((IPAddress)WiFi.gatewayIP());

  // print your MAC address:
  byte mac[6];
  WiFi.macAddress(mac);
  Serial.print("MAC address: ");
  printMacAddress(mac);
}

void printCurrentNet() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print the MAC address of the router you're attached to:
  byte bssid[6];
  WiFi.BSSID(bssid);
  Serial.print("BSSID: ");
  printMacAddress(bssid);
  // print the received signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI): ");
  Serial.println(rssi);

  // print the encryption type:
  byte encryption = WiFi.encryptionType();
  Serial.print("Encryption Type: ");
  Serial.println(encryption, HEX);
  Serial.println();
}

void printMacAddress(byte mac[]) {
  for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (mac[i] < 16) {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(mac[i], HEX);
    if (i > 0) {
      Serial.print(":");
    }
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

What can be the problem?
No working libs for WiFi uno rev 2?

Comment: can you connect to your mysql server from other computer?

Comment: Yes, that works.